# How can a Hydrogen make such a difference?

Tags: biochemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

Looking at familiar bodily fluids for a learning session. At first glance they both look the same. Then I noticed the N=C in biliverdin and HN-C in bilirubin. How can a N=C (imine group) and HN-C (secondary amine) make such a difference in colour? They look like structural isomers of each other to me. Or is there any stereoisomeric differences as well to this colour functional group change?

(Jaundice is directly related to bilirubin, urine is a product of bilirubin, I reckon there must be a real good reason and help aid from the colour change representation.)

e.g.

[image 1: bilirubin is a brown pigmented substance while biliverdin is green pigment](http://www.compoundchem.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/The-Chemistry-of-Bodily-Fluid-Colours.png)

[image]

[image2](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleHtml/2015/CC/c5cc06254c)

[image]

Comment: That's actually two hydrogens. The compound on the right is an oxidized form of the compound on the left.

Comment: @Zhe are you referring to first image? I don't see two hydrogens :@@ Bilirubin (brown) oxidised to create urobilinogen, then to urobilin for what we see in urine (yellow).

Comment: There are indeed two hydrogen atoms. There's one on the nitrogen and one that's implicitly associated with the missing double bond.

Comment: Actually there is little crucial on H yes or not. The entire pi system is changed in between.

Comment: Check how the conjugation is altered.

Comment: @Zhe so does this conjugation (resonance) result in the two molecules? Does it mean the interchange from -verdin to -rubin is easy and quick? And why would it takes long to reverse the process of someone having more bilirubin the body?

Comment: Not sure about that. The ease of oxidation/reduction is dependent on a bunch of factors that I can't claim to understand just by looking at the pair of the molecules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in structure of these two compounds is  perhaps the presence of a **more conjugated** structure in biliverdin compared to bilirubin. These products (*degradation products of haeme*<sup>1</sup>), just as most pigments, make use of the **conjugated electron systems to absorb visible light**, giving rise to strong colors. The long chain conjugated system in bilverdin leads to its strong green color, the reduced biliribin *(methenyl bridge*) has a less conjugated system with a different absorption consenquently different color.

This is a case of effects of conjugation in pigments than merely a difference in functional groups as I see it.

<sup>1</sup>*Note The degradation of haeme occurs at  the end of the red cells’  lifetime, where they are removed from the circulation and their components degraded, thus depends of many factors most importantly regulations carried out in the body, enzymes etc.*

**References**

- Voet and Voet Biochemistry Section 26-4. Amino Acids as Biosynthetic Precursors.
- [Conjugated system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugated_system)

Comment: I am terrible at replying, I took a look at your reply then, but usually take a long time to digest it, when not sure.